# Couchbase N1QL: Update on nested Documents

Tags: couchbase, document, sql++, nosql

When having a nested document like this:

```
{
"blog": "testblog1",
"user_id": 41,
"comments": [
    {
        "comment": "testcomment1",
        "user_id": 883
    },
    {
        "comment": "testcomment2",
        "user_id": 790
    }
  ]
}
```

can one do an Update Operation with N1QL to add an extra field to a subdocument?

I would like to add the field `"ranking" : "top comment"` to the subdocument with the comment testcomment2:

```
{
"blog": "testblog1",
"user_id": 41,
"comments": [
    {
        "comment": "testcomment1",
        "user_id": 883
    },
    {
        "comment": "testcomment2",
        "user_id": 790,
        "ranking" : "top comment"
    }
  ]
}
```

Site Note: The following statement would add a field to the root document on the Collection Blog:

```
UPDATE Blog SET rank = "top blog" WHERE blog = "testblog1";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do the following in N1QL:

UPDATE Blog 
SET c.ranking = "top comment" FOR c IN comments WHEN c.comment = "testcomment2" END 
WHERE blog = "testblog1"

Comment: how to access if it is nested array in 4.0.x couchbase

Comment: This solution does not work for me when using more than 1 set param.  For example, if I SET c.ranking = "top comment",  c.comment = "Winner!", it only updates 1 of the keys.  O_o

Comment: I think this is happening because I need to set a for statement in each set statement, but I need the same one for both... Suggestions?